# Premiere: Endless "Media Pending"

Tags: premiere

I was send a premiere project with all the raw-footage. It also included premiere preview-files.
When I open up the sequence, the program shows "media pending" forever. "Easy enough, I probably know why" - I thought. However, I tried pretty much everything, including:

- Clearing the entire cache
- Clearing the preview-files that came with the project
- Enabling and disabling the footage
- closing the program window and opening it again
- restarting, even reinstalling premiere
- opening the project on a different machine

And at this point I really don't know what to do anymore. Has anyone of you ever had that problem, and how does one fix it? Thanks in advance, have a beautiful day.

Edit: A Temporary fix was to find a machine on which the sequence loaded properly. Upon saving the project on that machine and re-opening that on the original machine, everything seems to work fine. Technically, the issue is solved, but there has to be some reason or reasonable fix for this, no? I would still love some tips on this issue.